# How to pass access token acquired by b2c authentication to Azure API Management Service from Angular/MVC application to Micro services

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I have created two different micro services.
I have created API application in B2C tenant and I am able to access both micro service APIs from client (MVC/Angular) application using token acquired by B2C authentication.
Now, I would like to access these two micro services from my client application via azure API management service.
I tried to follow below article but it seems out dated.
https://winterdom.com/2017/11/17/aad-b2c-api-management

Can some one please provide an article link or sample to match my requirement.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Thanks for the update @JamesZ, I need to some help to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Well then you should ask a question / tell what the problem is. SO isn't a coding service either.

Comment: You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

Comment: Thanks @TonyJu for the update, Steps provided in this article will work for Azure AD B2C ?

Comment: @Murthy I didn't test this before. But why do you want to project your api using b2c?

Comment: @TonyJu, Our requirement is that, we need to implement Azure active directory B2C local account authentication in web UI application along with micro services implementation. So, I have followed the steps mentioned in this ample (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi). I am able to login to azure AD B2C and able to get Bearer token using this method confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scope, account, Startup.Authority, false) for API token,everything is working fine. Want call those API from client application via Azure API mgmtService

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad. This also applies to Azure AD B2C.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the the response. Its working for requests with no input parameters like query string or JSON parameters. Do we need to configure some thing for Get and Post with input parameters like query string or  JSON input parameters.